# How do debug if my application has the launching issue

Tags: visual-c++

we made one application on Visual Studio 2008 , it  about to release. but now we are getting the crash while launching the application . could you please any give  a suggestion how do i debug on this particular issue

Comment: No one can help you with such little info. You need to provide more details about your issue.

Comment: For the above problem i am able to run  the Exe in debug mode but not in the release mode . could you please any one help me in solve this  problem .

Answer (score 0):

There could be a lot of reasons for your application's **Release** is crashing.

1. Did you link proper **Release** libraries with your application in Visual Studio project configuration ?
2. Check your code for some missing **Release** specific code.

My best guess is you are not linking to proper libraries for the **Release** version of your application.

Also, one reason could be that your application may be trying to load some file that may not exist. This happens with me sometimes when my **Release** build of application does not find file that it needs (Eg: OpenGL application trying to load a shader file that is missing); and you don't check for errors.

Comment: My experience is that using the wrong library configuration would not link successfully.  At the very least you'll get a conflict over bringing in two different run-time libraries.

Comment: @jdlugosz you are right, there would be a link-time error with wrong libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the Release build in the debugger, too.  Turn on debug-info settings in both the compiler and linker tabs (I think that was not the default in vs2008 and there were two distinct places to set) but don't change any optimization options or other setting.

Then launch the program from the debugger.  If the resulting EXE shows the crash when run normally but not when started via the debugger, there are more things to make the situations work the same (and that shows clues as to what is wrong, too).  So let us know if that still doesn't reproduce.